# OpenSubKey() returns null only one path in Registry. C++

Tags: c++-cli, registrykey

I am trying to open the sub key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData`.

I define it as such:

```
RegistryKey^ HkeylmPath32 = RegistryKey::OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive::LocalMachine, RegistryView::Registry32);
RegistryKey^ Test = HkeylmPath32->OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UserData");
```

But it returns null. I have various other registry calls in the program and they are all OK. It is just this one that is giving me issues. How can I fix this problem?

I ran this in PowerShell:

```
$uninstallkey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer"
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey('LocalMachine', 'Registry32')
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($uninstallkey)
$subkeys = $regkey.GetSubKeyNames()

write-host $reg
write-host $uninstallkey
write-host $regkey

foreach($key in $subkeys){
    write-host $key
}
```

This is the result:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer
Secure
```

Even though the uninstall key is showing that it is going to the 32-bit registry path. It is actually going through `Wow6432Node` to reach the Secure subkeyname in `Installer`.

Why? I have it declared to use the Registry32 view.

Comment: what CPU architecture is the application compiled for and what CPU architecture does your Windows have ?

Comment: Its all 64bit, thats why I defined the view as Registry32.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is stupid.  It seems I understood the view in reverse.  I had declared it to go to Registry32 and thinking it needed to go there for the additional subkeys, but it actually needed to go to the Registry64 view.